# Recursion over list inside list

Tags: haskell

I have some code like this:

```hs
data Set = Set String [Int]
  deriving (Show, Read)
```

```hs
getArr :: Set -> [Int]
getArr (Set _ arr) = arr
```

My goal is to write a function that will input a list of values into a tuple.
EG:
data --
`"One" [1], "Two" [2], "Three" [3]`
output: `"One" [0, 1], "Two" [1,2], "Three" [3,3]` with the input being [0, 1, 3]

My general aproach to this was to go recursively over the data going one by one and at the same time going over the list of values one by one using : to add it onto the first index.

I attempted to do something like:

```hs
addToSet :: [Set] -> [Int] -> [Set]
addToSet [] [] = []
addToSet (x:xs) (y:ys) = (getArr x : y) ++ addToSet xs
```

but i get an error saying :

````
Couldn't match type ‘[Int]’ with ‘Set’
  Expected type: [Set]
    Actual type: [[Int]]```
````

Comment: there is a lot going on here - first `get Arr x : y` would result in a `Int`-list (result of `getArr`) being prepended to a [Int]` (the `y`) - then the result of that (what ever it is supposed to be) is concatenated with a `[Int] -> [Set]` (you only partial applied `xs` to `addToSet`) ... also: can you please make a better example (input to `addToSet` and expected output)? Your example on the first half does not seem to associated to the second half at all

Answer (score 1):

Consider the helper function

```
updateSet :: Set -> Int -> Set
updateSet (Set s xs) y = Set s (y:xs)
```

This simply adds a single value to a given set:

```
>>> updateSet (Set "One" [1]) 0
Set "One" [0,1]
```

Then `addToSet` is just a wrapper around `zipWith`:

```
addToSet :: [Set] -> [Int] -> [Set]
addToSet = zipWith updateSet
```

`updateSet` is called on the first set and the first integer, then the second set and the second integer, and so on, with the results combined in order in a single list.

---

Another way to think of this is mapping a function of type `(Set, Int) -> Int` over the result of zipping the two lists together:

```
updateSet' :: (Set, Int) -> Set
updateSet' (Set s xs, y) -> Set s (y:xs)

addToSet :: [Set] -> [Int] -> [Set]
addToSet ss is = map updateSet' (zip ss is)
```

Note that `updateSet' = uncurry updateSet`.

Comment: I understand your explanation and appreciate it but I tried running ```addToSet(sampleSet [0, 1, 3])``` but im getting an error

Comment: The parentheses are used wrong. The call is simply `addToSet sampleSet [0, 1, 3]`.

Comment: Specifically, parentheses aren't used in function calls, unless to define a subexpression as a single argument. The function call itself is *just* the function and its argument separated by a space. Note that `foo x y` is *two* function calls: `foo x` returns a function which is then applied to `y`. Informally, you can think of that as a single call to `foo` taking two arguments.

Comment: I sometimes wonder whether we do new Haskellers a disservice with the "function application is juxtaposition" line. Maybe it would be kinder to teach them "all functions take one argument" and "use parens for application" just like other languages. So `foo(x)(y)(z)` because we apply `foo` to `x`, then apply `foo(x)` to `y`, then apply `foo(x)(y)` to `z`. Then at some later date, we can tell them that as a notational convenience you're allowed to drop parens around single tokens or something. ...but I'm sure there'd be some new confusion then that the current way doesn't have. Sigh.

Comment: Im coming from Java and C++, for my its hard to grasp haskell since the way you program in it is so much different so something simple as recursion has to be done in weird ways (which is to me) like this

Comment: Haskell just uses higher level abstractions. `map` and `zip` basically "hide" the recursion from you, by representing very commonly used patterns. It's similar to how you can write `a + b`, rather than iterating over the bits of `a` and `b` yourself and using AND and XOR to implement the half-adders.